# Property 'canActivate' in type 'AuthGuard' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'. How can I fix it?

Tags: angular, observable, guard

I'm writing a guard that either grants access to a page or it doesn't. It depends on the status of the server's response after I make a request to it. Since the canActivate guard can take Observable values, I don’t subscribe and return an Observable and I’m already trying to create a condition under which, in case of an error, access to the page will be denied and a redirect to the login page will occur, and in case of a response of 200, the user will have access to page.
How can I implement logic that will be do it?

My simple route:

```
const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return res.status(401);
  }
  next();
};

router.get("/isAuthenticated", isAuth, (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200);
});
```

Function from service:

```
isAccessToLobby$() {
    return this.http.get(
      `${environment.domain}${BackendRoutes.Authentication}`,
      this.httpOptions
    );
}
```

And my guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError, map, of, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import Paths from './paths';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}
  canActivate() {

    return this.authService.isAccessToLobby$().pipe(
      map((el) => of(true)),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.router.navigate([`${Paths.Login}`]);
        return of(false);
      })
    );

  }
}
```

Finally I get this error:

```
  Type '() => Observable<boolean | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<...>'.
    Type 'Observable<boolean | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'.
      Type 'Observable<boolean | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean | UrlTree>'.
        Type 'boolean | Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree'.
          Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree'.
```

Comment: Hello. Using `map()` operator you don't have to wrap your value into `Observable` because `map()` wrapping by himself any value returned from it. So, instead of `map((el) => of(true))` should be `map(() => true)`. Not absolutely sure that it will help but you can try anyway)))

Comment: @alexJS it's solved this error, thanks, but my code still doesn't work))

Comment: Interesting))) How do you add this guard to you route? Do you use something like `app-routing.module.ts`? Honestly, I have doubts about `providedIn: 'root'` in the `@Injectable` decorator... but not sure.